# Ignoring spell-check for a particular word in RichTextBox in wpf

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, spell-checking

In my application I need to ignore the spell-checker for some specific words,how to do that.I am using WPF RichTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF 4.0 Custom Dictoinaries are allowed not in WPF 3.5...

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/46fcd53a-310b-4a78-963e-8c1b8a08b174) link might help you with the Topic